# How to create a list of expression values?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a list that looks like this `[2^1,2^2, .... ,2^10]`.

When I tried this code:

```
for n in range (0,11):
    result=pow(2,n)
```

It just got the result `2^10`.

How do I create the list I showed above, using a `for`loop?

Comment: because you are re-writing the contents of `result` in to `result` with iteration in your loop. You are trying to create a list of items, therefore your `result` should be a *list* and you should use `append` hold each value in your iteration -> `result.append(pow(2,n))`. Don't forget to set `result = []` before your loop.

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the values in a list. Try using a list comprehension:

```
result = [pow(2,n) for n in range(0, 11)]
print result #[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
```

However, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20970087/2), the `**` is less expensive than `pow` (less overhead due to the lack of a function call), albeit with a very small difference.

Comment: This is the most "Pythonic" answer in my opinion. However, I think it would also be a good idea to mention to the OP that using the `pow()` function is slightly more expensive than using the built-in power operator `**`, so the latter might be preferred.

Comment: @ChristianDean true, and it preserves the OP's initial approach well too. I will include `**` vs `pow`.

Comment: Note: If performance was really a concern `2**n` is just `1` shifted left `n` times, i.e. `1 << n`.

Answer (score 2):

Start by making result a list. Next you have to make sure that result is tabbed in so it is part of the for loop. Then you have to append the result of the pow to the list. Otherwise you are just reassigning the value of result. Also if u want the first to be 2^1 you need to start at 1 not zero. Hope this helps

```
  result = []
  for n in range(1,11):
      result.append(pow(2,n))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the result to a list, you're setting the `result` every iteration, therefore showing 2^10 as that is the last iteration.

Try

```
result.append(pow(2,n))
```

And make sure result is a list

Edit: You could also forget the loop and do it with a comprehensive list:

```
mylist = [pow(2, i) for i in range(0, 11)]
```

In this case its rather simple.